# Resizing instances through the amazon ec2 .net api

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Im trying to modify the size of an ec2 instance from within a .net program.

E.g. set an instance from 1GB ram to 2GB etc.

The amazon documentation does not seem to have any clear explanation. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_ModifyReservedInstances.html

Is there no simple way to do this, for example:

```
Instance instance = Instance.GetById(xx);
instance.SetType( "small-1.1" );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't simply edit the RAM amount of an instance, as it is bound to the instance type. But you can change the instance type (after you stopped it).

See this API: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_ModifyInstanceAttribute.html